# One tape Turing machine for doubling words(strings)

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, turing-machines

I am going to design a Turing machine for doubling any words. My algorithm is such that for word $X$ as input, the output will be in the form $X@X$ which $@$ is a character. How can design an one-tape Turing machine that give exactly $XX$ as its output? For example, X=abba, XX=abbaabba. Thank you in advance for consideration.

Comment: If you know how to turn X into X@X, add to that the algorithm that will find the '@' and swap it to the character to the right, as long as there *is* a character to the right - effectively moving '@' to the end?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247467/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143855/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).